# The set of all the indices of the members of a set

Tags: logic

Given $X^{i} := \{x^{i}, x^{j1}, \cdots, x^{jn}\}$, I am interested in the set of all the indices of the members of $X^{i}$, which in this case is $\{i, j1, \cdots, jn\}$. Let $Q(i,j)$ be a binary relation. Then considering the free variable $i$, which one of the following formulas is syntactically and semantically valid and meaningful?

(1) $(\forall j \in [(\arg\limits_{k} x^{k} \in X^{i})\setminus\{i\}])~~~Q(i,j)$

(2) $(\forall j \in [(\arg x^{k} \in X^{i})\setminus\{i\}])~~~Q(i,j)$

(3) $(\forall j \in [(\arg\limits_{k} \forall x^{k} \in X^{i})\setminus\{i\}])~~~Q(i,j)$

(4) $(\forall j \in [(\arg \forall x^{k} \in X^{i})\setminus\{i\}])~~~Q(i,j)$

Comment: What does your square brackets notation mean? What is $\arg$?

Comment: @RobArthan: The brackets are just used to indicate the precedence of the applied operators. So, one can simply replace them by parenthesis or curly braces. Furthermore, `arg` is supposed to return the indice(s) of its argument.

Comment: This isn't standard mathematical notation. Please supply some more context.

Comment: @RobArthan: Sorry, but I don't know what you mean by more context. As I noted in the question, all I need is the correct notation to iterate over the set of all the indices of the members of a specific set. In particular `arg` works like `argmax`, except the former returns all arguments, but the latter reflects the arguments of the maximum value of a set.

Comment: @RobArthan: In other words, I intend to mathematically define the index set of a set. By definition, the index set includes the indices of the members of that set.

Comment: By asking you for more context, I am asking you to tell us more about where the question comes from and what the notation you are using means. Your description of $\arg$ is incomprehensible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This way of combining `arg` with quantifiers looks a bit awkward. Instead, I would define an index set as follows.

> Given $X^{i} := \{x^{i}, x^{j1}, \cdots, x^{jn}\}$, $I_{X}$ is the *index
>   set* of $X^{i}$ denoting the set of all the indices of the
>   elements of $X^{i}$ as follows         \begin{equation}
>    I_{X^{i}} := \{\arg\limits_{k} x^{k} | \forall
>  x^{k} \in X^{i}\},   \end{equation}          where $\arg(\cdot)$
>   operator returns the index of its arguments.

Now, one can simply say

$(\forall j \in I_{X^{i}})~~~ Q(i,j)$